# Is row level filtering by logged in user an Anti-pattern?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

So I have ran into this at many organizations/programs is they HEAVILY steer away from filtering datasets by the logged in user.

Can someone explain to me why this is the case? This seems like a fairly simple reporting feature.

Comment: Maybe the *malicious* user can log in with other user name?

Comment: I mean, sure? I guess. But that wouldnt change the issue even filtered based on role/department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Row level security/filtering has its place in specialized scenarios, but in general the avoidance you are seeing revolves around the convention that security and business logic belong in the application domain and not in the database.

Beyond that, row level security/filtering adds complications for development and troubleshooting.  Data aggregations of selectively filtered data are problematic too, especially when you start looking at broadly scoped data filtered by role/department silos.

This can very well open a huge can of worms whereby end users are comparing outputs which don't match (based on hidden, variant filtering), and this can lead to increased support requests and harmful user perception of bad data quality/integrity even if the filtering and data are correct.